# How to zip the particular type of file in a directory

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am having three kinds of files in a directory like *.txt*, *.csv* and files with no extensions.

Example

```
test
nest
prod
test.csv
prod.txt
nest.csv
```

I want to zip the files with no extension and move that zip to another directory. Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` with an invert condition on the `-name` field with a glob pattern that matches names containing dot character, as below

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec zip filename.zip "{}" + 
[ -f filename.zip ] && mv filename.zip /to_whatever_path_needed/
```

The expression gets all the files *not* having a `.` character in their names and passes it to zip in one-shot to create the `.zip` archive.

You might have to add the depth options to `find` as `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` if you want to locate the files *only* within your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using [***tar***](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1) utility:

```
tar -cvf noext.zip --exclude=*.* * && mv noext.zip path/to/dest_dir
```

---

- `-c` - create a new archive
- `--exclude=*.*` - exclude files based upon *PATTERN*
- `mv noext.zip path/to/dest_dir` - move created archive to the *destination* directory

Comment: That link you give is of a RedHat copy of a man page written by Debian for GNU tar. You need bsdtar for support for zip files though and add the `-a` option (GNU `tar` would create a tar file with a zip extension). You'd want to quote the `*.*`. You can also do `bsdtar -acvf path/to/dest_dir/noext.zip --exclude='*.*' *` directly.

Comment: Sorry, `--exclude='*.*'` would exclude `.` just like any directory and and file in any directory whose name contains `.`.

Answer (score 0):

In ksh:

```
zip /another/directory/files_without_extension.zip !(*.*)
```

In bash, run `shopt -s extglob` then the command above. In zsh, run `setopt ksh_glob` then the command above, or alternatively

```
setopt extended_glob
zip /another/directory/files_without_extension.zip ^*.*
```